# Modelling phase noise for self-heterodyne method

Tags: noise, phase

I am trying to model the phase noise $\phi(t)$ of laser used in self-heterodyne method using python code. The noise is time-dependent.  The noise follows the condition that

$$\langle(\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau))^2\rangle = \exp(-\tau/\tau c),$$
where < > represents the mean value.  I know this noise model can be generated using some stochastic process, but I don't know, since I don't have much knowledge in this area.  Can someone suggest me some references, code, etc to help me model this phase noise?

Comment: It sounds like this may be about modeling the behavior of a laser -- which may be better done on physics.stackexchange.com.  You'd need to be careful how you ask the question because _someone_ there will know all about lasers, but probably less about signal processing.  I'm sure that the phase noise will be heavily dependent on the laser's coherence length; I'm less sure that the actual relationship will be as simple as the one you've given.

Comment: If you do want to persist with this question on this group, could you _edit your question_ to cite the source of your noise equation?